# How to navigate to a new screen in flutter, while still keeping the bottomNavigationBar

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Hy Guys, I'm currently developing an app with Flutter and i'm in the profile Page. I wan't to be able to navigate from the profile page to the settings page without it changing the bottom navigation bar [Something Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEy48.png)

NOTE: The navigation happens within the same tab. I'm not asking for how to switch between tabs

Answer (score 2):

in the  [Bottom Navigation Bar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) the pages are the tabs

and this is a [full example](https://github.com/nisrulz/flutter-examples/tree/master/using_bottom_nav_bar)

```
new Scaffold(
      body: new TabBarView(
        children: <Widget>[new FirstTab(), new SecondTab(), new ThirdTab()],
        controller: controller,
      ),
bottomNavigationBar: new TabBar(
          tabs: <Tab>[
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite),
            ),
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.adb),
            ),
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.airport_shuttle),
            ),
          ])
```

Comment: thats not what I meant. I mean how do I navigate between screens (still within the same tab). Because using Navigator.push always hides the bottom tab

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I wanted. Except one issue. In the body: new TabBarView(....), I already have that body taken up with a Container, with a form inside that container. Any idea how to put multiple items within the body of a Scaffold?